# How can I manually edit boot.ini in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, multi-boot

I have installed another new different copy of windows 7 on a different hard drive in my computer running a win7 version.I am seeing both my win 7 files in different drives and intact. But what I found that my previous win7 version is not showing in startup boot menu. All I find that the last installed version boots up be default without giving any options for selecting desired OS.

Is it possible I can manually add my previous windows entry (E:\Windows) in this boot menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of touching the boot.ini file, you could use programs such as EasyBCD or BCEdit.

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/